# AffdexMe, Android, LicenseException: could not open license file

Tags: java, android, affdex-sdk

I cloned affdex-me for android from [github](https://github.com/Affectiva/affdexme-android) and successfully build the gradle,but when running the app, it closed and error, I have put the license and rename it as the tutorial shown

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.affectiva.affdexme.debug, PID: 17554 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.affectiva.affdexme.debug/com.affectiva.affdexme.MainActivity}:
com.affectiva.android.affdex.sdk.LicenseException: could not open license file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which tutorial you were using but I checked our developer portal and it wasn't as clear as it could have been so I updated the instructions.  The updated versions are:

- http://developer.affectiva.com/v3/android/analyze-camera/
- http://developer.affectiva.com/v3/android/analyze-video/
- http://developer.affectiva.com/v3/android/analyze-frames/
- http://developer.affectiva.com/v3/android/analyze-photo/

The gist of it is: copy the license file to the app/main/src/assets/Affdex directory and pass the filename to the setLicensePath() method.

```
detector.setLicensePath("affdex.license");
```